# Evaluate a complex integral and determine if it contradicts Cauchy's theorem

Tags: complex-integration

I'm trying to determine if $\oint_C \frac{dz}{z-3}=0$ where $|z-2|=5$
and if it contradicts Cauchy's theorem.  I assume it won't be $0$, and then it won't contradict Cauchy's theorem because $C$ isn't centered at the origin, it's centered at $(2,0)$.  I'm stuck on evaluating the integral though.  Here is what I have:

$$z=2+5e^{i\theta}, f(z)=\frac{1}{2+5e^{i\theta}-3},  dz=5ie^{i\theta}d\theta$$

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{5ie^{i\theta}}{5e^{i\theta}-1}d\theta$$
I don't know what to do with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert to real integrals.

\begin{align*}\DeclareMathOperator{\i}{i\!} \DeclareMathOperator{\rme}{e}
\DeclareMathOperator{\diff}{d}
 I &= \int_0^{2\pi} \frac {\i 5 \rme^{\i t}} {5\rme^{\i t} - 1} \diff t \\
&= \i \int_0^{2\pi} \frac {5 \rme^{\i t} (5\rme ^{-\i  t} - 1)} {(5\rme^{\i t} -1)(5\rme^{-\i t} - 1)} \diff t\\
&= \i \int_0^{2\pi} \frac {25 - 5 \rme^{-\i t}}{26-10\cos(t)}\diff t \\
& = \i \int_0^{2\pi} \frac {25-5\cos(t) + 5\i \sin(t)}{26-10\cos(t)}\diff t \\
&= \i \int_0^{2\pi} \frac {25 - 5\cos(t)}{26-10\cos(t)}\diff t - \int_0^{2\pi} \frac {5\sin(t)} {26-10\cos(t)} \diff t \\
&=: \i I_1 + I_2. 
\end{align*}
For $I_2$, note that $\diff(-\cos(t)) = \sin(t)$, thus 
$$
I_2 = \frac 12 \int_0^{2\pi} \frac {\diff(13-5\cos(t))}{13-5\cos(t)} =\frac 12 \log(13 -5 \cos(t))|_0^{2\pi} = 0. 
$$
For $I_1$:
$$
I_1 = \pi + \frac 12\left(\int_0^{\pi} + \int_\pi^{2\pi} \right)\frac {12 \diff t}{13-5\cos(t)}, 
$$
while 
$$
 \int_\pi^{2\pi} \frac {12\diff t}{13-5\cos(t)} = \int_\pi^0 \frac {12}{13 -5 \cos(2\pi -u)} \diff (2\pi - u) = \int_0^\pi \frac {12\diff u}{13- 5\cos(u)},
$$
thus 
\begin{align*}
I_1 &= \pi + 12\int_0^\pi \frac {\diff t}{13-5\cos(t)} \\
&= \pi +24 \int_0^\pi \frac {\sin(t/2)^2 + \cos(t/2)^2} {8\cos(t/2)^2 + 18\sin(t/2)^2} \diff (t/2)\\
&= \pi + 24 \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac {\diff (\tan(u))}{8 + 18 \tan(u)^2} \\
&= \pi + 3 \cdot \frac 23\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac {\diff (3\tan(u)/2)}{1 + (3\tan(u)/2)^2}\\
&= \pi + 2 \cdot \frac \pi 2 = 2\pi. 
\end{align*}

Therefore $I= \i I_1 + I_2= \i 2\pi$. This does not contradict Cauchy theorem, because if we let $\varGamma$ be $\{z \colon |z - 3| = 1\}$ with the clockwise orientation then $\varGamma \cup C$ encloses an region on which $1/(z-3)$ is analytic, so the integral is actually $I= \int_{\varGamma^-} \diff z/(z -3)$ by Cauchy theorem, which is 
$$
I = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac  {\i \rme^{\i t}}{\rme^{\i t}} \diff t = \i 2\pi
$$
that agree with the result from direct computation.